# String created from an array keeps returning null's

Tags: java, for-loop

```
String[] n = new String[8];

String name =  n[0] + n[1] + n[2] + n[3] + n[4] + n[5] + n[6] + n[7];

for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
    int h = 97;
    char j = (char) h;
    n[x] = String.valueOf(j);
}

System.out.println(name);
```

So I was experimenting with randomizing names but kept getting nulls returned so I tried narrowing down the problem as well as I could and used `h = 97` as a constant (this is the variable I was initially going to randomise) so I could be certain it couldn't go out of range. However something seems to go wrong in the for/loop because I tried creating the `name` string manually by adding values like `n[0] = String.valueOf(v);` on several lines and it worked perfectly.

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

You're concatenating the values in the array and assigning the result to `name` *before* you modify any of the values within the array... i.e. when every element of the array is `null`. Just move this line:

```
String name =  n[0] + n[1] + n[2] + n[3] + n[4] + n[5] + n[6] + n[7];
```

to *after* the loop instead of before it.

To make life simpler, you might want to use a `char` array instead:

```
char[] array = new char[8];
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
    array[x] = (char) 97; // Or whatever
}
String name = new String(array);
System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: Wow thanks for that fast response, moving the line really did make it work. I have some studying ahead it seems.